# Generate PNG for Google Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, svg, google-visualization, png, gantt-chart

I want to generate a PNG image from a Gantt Google Chart.
I've tried the `getImageURI()` method, but it only works for core charts.

I've also tried getting the *svg* element and converting it to PNG but it doesn't look the same as the one displayed in the browser.

Also I've tried [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) but without success.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**update**

from [google dev print png](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) tried
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3abx2vq/)

getting the svg element [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7ocxjzc/1/), then created a svg file from it, and converted it to png with an online converter, but it doesn't look the same.

Comment: Hard to answer without more details of what you've tried and failed e.g. a [mcve] of each case.

Comment: I updated the question with what I've tried

Comment: How did you tried to convert your svg to png ? Using [canvg library](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/master/canvg.js), I've got correct resuts : https://jsfiddle.net/L7ocxjzc/2/

Comment: @Kaiido it worked, ty
However, in high resolutions the image generated, has resolutions below the actual svg

Comment: Well svg is resolution agnostic, png is not... On high DPI screens, canvas needs to be scaled up, so you could check for `devicePixelRatio`, scale the canvas you pass there by this dPR, then call canvg with these options : `{ignoreDimensions: true,
    scaleWidth: canvas.width,
    scaleHeight: canvas.height}`

Comment: that worked, thank you